# Can the evap canister valve be ordered and replaced separately for a 2001 Toyota Camry

Tags: toyota, camry, evap

I'm tripping some codes for the check engine light and took my car in to get repaired. They did a smoke test and are fairly certain that I need to replace a valve on the canister (there are others that aren't on the canister). The said that the dealer told them I needed to replace the whole canister because it is attached to the valve. Based on some of the documents I had the repair shop send me, I saw this part number 9091012264. That part looks like it can be ordered separately.

- Is there a diagram where I can see the parts in detail?
- Is that the valve on the canister?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can. You can find it as either **DORMAN Part # 911603**

[image]

or as **AIRTEX / WELLS Part # 2M1257**.

[image]

Comment: Those two parts look pretty different...Why is that?

Comment: Different manufacturer. There are really only two differences to the parts: 1) color; 2) top plug is backwards. Take a look at yours and order accordingly.